# Using regex with XML

Tags: php, regex, cdata

I'm trying to use regular expressions to extract the CDATA from the following XML feed: http://www.patrickarundell.net/THREE-IE-FEED.asp

My code is as follows:

```
$xml = file_get_contents('http://www.patrickarundell.net/THREE-IE-FEED.asp');

$arr = array();
preg_match('/(CDATA)(.*)/', $xml, $arr);
echo '<pre>';
    print_r($arr);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output is:

```
Array
(
    [0] => CDATA[
    [1] => CDATA
    [2] => [
)
```

I know I don't have the regular expression quite right, but when I try the following statement:

```
preg_match('/(<![CDATA[)(.*)/', $xml, $arr);
```

I get an error:

> Warning: preg_match() [function.preg-match]: Compilation failed: missing terminating ] for character class at offset 15

I thought this might give me the details after the square bracket '[', which is what I'm looking for.

Any help appreciated, I've been trying this for a few hours and having no luck.

Comment: Did you consider a XML parser?

Comment: Yes, I'm using SimpleXMLElement to parse the rest of the file and that works fine. Its doesn't give me any problems. But I can't get the details in the CDATA part using SimpleXMLElement. If you see the XML file the actual horoscope detail is under the <horoscope> node. When I reference this node, it lumps all the data in together.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for the error message is that it is missing a closing `]` for a character class. But you didn't want to define a character class with your `[` you want to match it, so you nedd to escape it `\[`.

```
<!\[(CDATA)\[\s*(.*?)\s*\]\]>
```

I tested it here on [regexr](http://regexr.com?2tl3u)

The `.*?` is a non greedy match, it matches as less as possible, until it finds the closing `]]>`.

Comment: stema, thanks for this. just one question, I managed to get the first CDATA value into the array. But as you can see from the XML there are a number of other CDATA segments. how do I manage these ?

Comment: @Stephen, I don't know php very well, but there is a function `preg_match_all`, try using this instead of `preg_match`. According to [this documentation](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) it should do what you want.